# Modular Arithmetic with high exponent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

HOW?How do I simplify this expression?

> $276^{247} \mod 323$

Thank you so much.

Comment: See also [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/81228).

Comment: Although it's a bit unfortunate that after getting some answers to your [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2499046/1) about $382^{295} \bmod 11$ you have [changed it](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2499046/2) to $276^{247} \bmod 323$. Meta: [Question edited to change meaning](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fermat's little theorem.

It tells us that $a^{10}\equiv 1 \bmod 11$ if $a$ is not a multiple of $10$.

It follows that $382^{295}= 382^{290} 382^{5}\equiv 1^{29}382^{5}=382^5\bmod 11$

This last one is easy to work out.

Answer (score 0):

$$382^{295} \mod 11 \equiv 8^{295} \mod 11$$

This is by the definitions in modular arithmetic

If you are familiar with Fermat's little theorem, then you will know that $$p^{q-1} \mod q \equiv 1$$ if q is a prime and p is relatively prime to q

Therefore, we can rewrite it as

$$8^{295} \mod 11 \equiv 8^{10 \cdot 29} \cdot 8^5 \mod 11 \equiv 1^{29} \cdot {-3}^5 \mod 11 \equiv -243 \mod 11 \equiv 10 \mod 11$$